# Is signed type valid for each element using typedef + packed array (v.s. multidimensional packed array)

Tags: typedef, system-verilog, signed, packed

I have a question about signed property with multiple packed dimensions which is defined in stages with typedef.

Basically,

```
logic signed [1:0][2:0] foo;
```

* foo[0] is not signed (signed is meaningless if you expect signed element) because all entire packed array is signed but each element is not signed.

But,

```
typedef logic signed [1:0] foo_t;
foo_t [2:0] foo;
```

* foo[0] is signed. What a strange..

Q1> What happens? Why is it signed??

Q2> Is it same declaration with
    logic signed [1:0][2:0] foo; // ??

Q3> LRM says that [1:0] index varies most rapidly, which is not my expectation.
    logic signed [2:0][1:0] foo; //??

Answer (score 4):

This is an artifact of the allowed syntax(BNF). The `signed` keyword applies *signedness* to the identifier as a whole, not to the individual elements (`logic`) you are packing. There's no syntax that allowes you to control the *signedness* of each dimension except by the typedef stages you discovered.

When you create a multidimensional array in stages, each dimension you add varies less rapidly than the previous. So dimensionally, your typedef is equivalent to

```
logic signed [2:0][1:0] foo;
foo_t [2:0] foo; // the [2:0] gets added to the left of [1:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If use an unpacked array, we can also keep signed property for each element.

```
logic signed [1:0] foo [2:0];
```

But, it seems that array of typedef with unpacked array is not supported by systemverilog.

```
typedef logic signed data_t [3:0];
data_t [2:0] foo;
```

When I try this, compiler shows an error

“illegal element type for a vector (vector element type must be an integral type)”. -  you may leave any comment for this.

Anyway, thanks for your answer.